# cannot access property - JS Error Shown

Tags: javascript

My Code to access a property:

```js
var myArray = [{"td_stlmnt":"NN2015227","Heading":"NN2015227[02/12/2015]","td_scripcd":"514286","Order#":"1000000003042299","Trade#":"1124070","Time":"14:40:38","Security":"ASHIMASYN (514286)","Buy":"250","Sell":"0","Market Rate":"12.90","Brokerage":"12.50","Buy Value":"3237.5000","Sell Value":".0000","_":"","Ordr":"ASHIMASYNb","BDate":"20151202","Net Value":""},{"td_stlmnt":"NN2015227","Heading":"NN2015227[02/12/2015]","td_scripcd":"514286","Order#":"1000000003042299","Trade#":"1124072","Time":"14:40:38","Security":"ASHIMASYN (514286)","Buy":"250","Sell":"0","Market Rate":"12.90","Brokerage":"12.50","Buy Value":"3237.5000","Sell Value":".0000","_":"","Ordr":"ASHIMASYNb","BDate":"20151202","Net Value":""}];

alert(myArray[2].Order# );
```

```html
<html>
<body>


</body>
</html>
```

Getting an JS Error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string ->on alert - when I code as .Order# and if I use .Order then value is undefined.
what could be the possible solution ??

Comment: Please add the expected result, show us the JS, and format your JSON properly so it can be read (instead of being all in one line).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the bracket notation : `json[2]['Order#']`

You can't use `#` out of a string

```js
var myArray = [{"td_stlmnt":"NN2015227","Heading":"NN2015227[02/12/2015]","td_scripcd":"514286","Order#":"1000000003042299","Trade#":"1124070","Time":"14:40:38","Security":"ASHIMASYN (514286)","Buy":"250","Sell":"0","Market Rate":"12.90","Brokerage":"12.50","Buy Value":"3237.5000","Sell Value":".0000","_":"","Ordr":"ASHIMASYNb","BDate":"20151202","Net Value":""},{"td_stlmnt":"NN2015227","Heading":"NN2015227[02/12/2015]","td_scripcd":"514286","Order#":"1000000003042299","Trade#":"1124072","Time":"14:40:38","Security":"ASHIMASYN (514286)","Buy":"250","Sell":"0","Market Rate":"12.90","Brokerage":"12.50","Buy Value":"3237.5000","Sell Value":".0000","_":"","Ordr":"ASHIMASYNb","BDate":"20151202","Net Value":""}];

document.write(myArray[1]['Order#']);
```

Comment: if I add brackets I get js ERROR saying Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [

Comment: You should check what you wrote then, because this is valid.

Comment: I agree that this JSON is valid but I am not able to access the data in it still due to the JS Error in the syntax ... Googling it yet

Comment: I added a code snippet

Comment: Yea it worked .... the Bracket Notation is the only solution if you have spaces or special symbols like #. Thanx @Hacketo

Comment: Thanx everyone for the help you have done ....